# Primefaces line chart always use the minimum width and height

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I have two line charts which are controlled using Primefaces (Primefaces 5.2 on JSF 2.0, JavaEE 7 and Glassfish 4.1). I would like them to have their sizes resizable according to the window size (fit to the window). However, they appear to use the minimum sizes even when the window size is much larger. This leaves a lot of empty space on the screen.

The relevant JSF code:

```
      <p:layout>
    <p:layoutUnit styleClass="north-layout" position="north">
      <h:outputLink value="someLink" target="_blank"><p:graphicImage name="img/myLogo.jpeg" alt="default"/></h:outputLink>
     </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" class="my-center-layout" size="auto" resizable="true">    
      <p:panelGrid columns="2" class="chart-panel-grid">
        <p:panel class="my-chart-panel">
          <p:chart type="line" model="#{myController.newModel}" responsive="true"  id="newChart" class="my-line-chart"/>
        </p:panel>
        <p:panel class="my-chart-panel">
          <p:chart type="line" model="#{myController.usedModel}" responsive="true"  id="usedChart" class="my-line-chart"/>
        </p:panel>
      </p:panelGrid>
    </p:layoutUnit>
  </p:layout>
```

The CSS code:

```
.my-center-layout {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
}

.my-chart-panel {
  height: auto;
  width:  auto; 
  border: none;  
}

.my-line-chart {
  height: auto; 
  min-height: 200px;
  width:  auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  border: none;  
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `min-width`, if you want an element to shrink (or grow) infinitely up to the smallest possible window size? Remove `min-width` (and `min-height`, if needed). Otherwise, the element will not shrink beyond the `min-width` horizontally. (And better use `styleClass` in place of `class`, whenever needed).

Comment: PrimeFaces 5.3 has responsive charts

Comment: @Tiny The problem is that the chart will still use min-width and min-height when window is much larger. If I remove those two, the charts will disappear. I will edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: @Kukeltje I will try 5.3 later but we cannot use it right now.

Comment: Remove all custom css and see how it behaves then. Also from all components/html up the tree

Comment: It seems that the panel won't fit the window once the <p:panelGrid> is used.